# How to justify text perfectly on iOS 7

Tags: ios, typography, textkit

I'm trying to horizontally align text bits with different size and fonts.

Here is the result I'd like (made with scribus):

[image: mockup]

You can see that text is horizontally align perfectly (to the pixel).

I tried implementing this with a basic UITextView, and justifying the text. Here is what I got:

[image: justified]

You can see that the text is not horizontally aligned to the pixel.
I tried centering and it's still not good enough:

[image: centered]

If things were not hard enough, the first and third line are dynamic text... so their size changes.

I had a look at textkit but didn't find anything conclusive...

My leads are:

1. find best font size for text given the width.
2. space glyphs evenly so that the text bounding box is equal to the desired width.

but I have no clue how to do that.
Any leads ? thanks !

Comment: Just a suggestion, you could use an image rather than tan text, and change the image to a different one when you want to do whatever you're doing with your dynamic text if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NSString's `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`?

```
CGRect rect = [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, height) 
                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading 
                                attributes:attributes
                                   context:nil];
```

If you are also supporting iOS 6, use `-[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]`

```
CGSize textSize = [string sizeWithFont:uifont
                     constrainedToSize:maximumCGSize
                         lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
```

The `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method has been deprecated as of iOS 7.

Using one of these methods, you can find the line that is the widest and match the others to it. In your case of dynamic text, I would suggest against using UITextView to ensure text is correctly justified.